# Django 3.1 media prefix not showing on urls

Tags: django

I am using Django 3.1.

settings.py looks like

```
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve(strict=True).parent.parent

MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'media'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

urls.py looks like

```
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    ...
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

my model image field looks like

```
dev_image_one = models.ImageField(upload_to='dev/', blank=True, null=True, verbose_name = 'image 1')
```

When files are uploaded, they end up in the /media/dev directory.

When they are to be displayed, the url looks like:

```
<img src="dev/1.png">
```

If I manually append /media/ on to the front of the url, the image displays. I never had this problem before so I'm at a loss as to what is going wrong. I never used 3.1 before, so I'm wondering if that doesn't have something to do with it. No problem with the static files. Thanks.

Comment: please share the related template code

Answer (score 2):

Make sure settings.py be like

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR / "static",
]

MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'media'

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

load `{% load static %}` in any page that you want to access image

use `{% static 'images/india.jpg' %}` to acess image